# How can I bypass grant access dialog when opening Excel,word or powerpoint file using apple scripts

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

OS : MacOS High Seirra (10.13.6)

I am using below code to open a Excel file from apple scripts

```
  `set excelFile to "TestExcel_ReadOnly.xlsx"
    set filepath to ¬
        ((folder of file (path to me) of application "Finder" as text) ¬
            & excelFile) as alias
    set sourcePath to POSIX path of filepath

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        activate
        open sourcePath
    end tell`
```

Then I will get a dialog asking to grant permission, I want to get rid of this as I want to run these apple scripts remotely[image]

Answer (score -1):

This may work around the problem:

`with timeout of 5 seconds
try
open FileName
on error
--Cancel and Grant Access dialog pops up and stops execution. Click the Grant Access button to continue script execution.

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Excel" to tell button "Grant Access" of window "Open" of application process "Microsoft Excel" of application "System Events" to perform action "AXPress"
end try
end timeout`